# Go get not working in Atom

Tags: go, atom-editor

So I've installed Atom on Windows 7 and I wanted to try out Go language in that. I installed a package called `go-plus`, but it needed 2 more things to install:

[image]

So I clicked Run Go Get, but I get this error:

[image]

I tried it on Debian and on Manjaro and after runing Run Go Get it just works. So I thought about running `go get -u ...` in my cmd, it worked, but still when I open Atom those 2 messages pop out. How can I deal with it?

Comment: You must set your `GOPATH` environment variable to point to your go workspace. Have you set it? You can check it by clicking on the `go-plus` icon at the bottom of Atom. You can also run `go env` in your command line.

Comment: `set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Frynio\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.12.7\"C:\work"
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Frynio\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build503348538=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1`

Comment: Looks like your `GOPATH` variable contains an invalid path. Set it to point to the folder which contains your `src`, `pkg` and `bin` folders.

Comment: I mean, in env variables its set to C:\work, but Atom sets it to a different path

Comment: Doesn't look like it is... Run `go env`, and show only the line which contains `GOPATH`. You should not use `C:`, as that is the _working directory_ on drive `C`, which may change. Use an absolute path.

Comment: `set GOPATH=C:\work`

Comment: The `set` command only sets the environment variable in the current shell (command line). Please restart Atom and verify by clicking on the `go-plus` icon at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Atom doesn't accept the path with "", so I just removed them and it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `go get` command downloads and installs packages in your go workspace, as denoted by the `GOPATH` environment variable. You must set this first for Atom to be able to download utilities.

You may use the `go env` command to verify, also you can click on the `go-plus` icon at the bottom of Atom to see the `GOPATH` value visible to Atom.

Your screenshots and comments indicate you have an invalid folder value in your `GOPATH`. Easiest is to set it to a single, absolute folder. You can read more about it here:

[How to Write Go Code: The `GOPATH` environment variable](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)